# ArcGIS export data in Shape from Oracle

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, export, oracle-spatial

I connected my Oracle database to ArcGIS and added one layer to map. This layer has points and polygons. I make a selection in this layer and get 9508 selected features, which I want to export as shapefile and add it separately to the map. I choose `Data > Export Data`, choose to export only selected features. But in the shapefile I get, there are less objects that were selected - only polygons, not points.

How can I properly create such layer file with selected points and polygons from Oracle database layer?

Comment: I drag and drop layer from DB connection...

Comment: What does your "layer [that] has points and polygons" look like in your table of contents?  Perhaps it is a group layer.  If so, then have you tried exporting a shapefile of points then exporting a shapefile of polygons, then adding both as layers, and finally grouping them?

Comment: You have your directionality backwards -- ArcGIS connects to the database, not the other way around.  ArcGIS requires that Query Layers contain exactly one topology class. Shapefiles are also restricted to exactly one topology class (plus null geometry).